# KeyError: key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I installed S3, and it works great on heroku. When I try to run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to push assets to heroku, it return the above error. If I run heroku config, it already has the S3 bucket and everything else set.

What is it looking for, and why can't it find S3 name just to compile assets.

In production.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: 'us-west-2',
    }
 }
```

I've found a couple SO on this, but none are pointing me towards a solution. Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:
The reason I have to compile locally is because heroku is taking out the application.js file.

```
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2016-09-23T15:12:53.753671 #267]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_97a8fe2ca07bc4bf090be26f2be2872b/public/assets/application-9c608f99ae2b1980d74ba674b9f9ff7f0ae113d532e2c2ea580960a6a53346bb.js
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (6.54s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote:        I, [2016-09-23T15:12:55.908630 #273]  INFO -- : Removed application-489c5647af1ca8b6a56e560e8a83d77a1a070778dabb4f0b40f55c4a4e5b8feb.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compile assets locally, where the `S3_BUCKET_NAME` config property on Heroku has no effect.

If you want to run your app locally (this includes running Rake tasks), you need to define that environment variable.

That said, this statement makes no sense:

> When I try to run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to push assets to heroku,

There is no reason to you need to run `rake assets:precompile` locally to "push assets" to Heroku. Heroku will automatically compile your assets for you each time you push new commits to it.

Comment: This actually is the issue. When I push to heroku, it takes out application.js. So I'm trying to compile it locally so it is pushed to heroku. I will update the error with the log error. Just for your knowledge, I was compiling locally just fine before i installed S3

Comment: @gwalshington You've misdiagnosed your problem. Compiling assets locally and pushing them to Heroku is the wrong answer here. Heroku is not removing your application.js, it's removing the *old version* of your application.js

Comment: Actually, application.js is not in the project at all. Any thoughts as to why it wouldn't be there? And to confirm it isn't there, I'm asking it just to console.log something when a page loads, and it isn't doing that.

Comment: And to the first response -- it is heroku's suggestion to compile locally to push to heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: @gwalshington Heroku makes that option available, but it doesn't *suggest* that you use it. If you've read the doc you linked to, you see how to turn off asset compilation on Heroku's end, which you don't appear to have done, since Heroku is still trying to compile your assets. Regardless, I've answered your question: Define the environment variable `S3_BUCKET_NAME` for your rake task to succeed.

Comment: Is your solution is to define S3_BUCKET_NAME in my production.rb? Because I have already done that. I'm confused as to what your suggestion is - it seems as if you're telling me to just not run that command on heroku.

Comment: No, the first two sentence of my answer. You need to define the environment variable, **locally**, `S3_BUCKET_NAME`. You've presumably set it with `heroku config:set` which has no affect on your ability to run your app locally. See [Heroku local](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local) or search for how to set an environment variable in your operating system.